# Change filetype icons in intellij idea 2016.3

Tags: intellij-idea

Since the update to idea 2016.3 we have the new icons for different filetypes:

[image]

However, the icon for js files reminds the same as before (in Projects)

[image]

I've tried to change the icon in settings / editor / filetypes, but there the icon already is the new one

[image]

How do I change the icon so that I have the new one for js files too?